# GeoPDF viewer for Linux OS

Tags: linux, geopdf

Is there a GeoPDF viewer for Linux / Fedora?

Or ... is there some simple cartopy / mpl / gdal code that will display GeoPDF?

FYI, here's a browser for US Topo GeoPDF files: https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

Comment: Evince should be able to view pdf's on linux https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince

Comment: Evince can view pdfs, and in Geopdf it can also show or hide different layers. But it cannot show attributes in these layers (this is possible in Adobe Reader). I am looking also for a pdf viewer (for linux OS) that can also display the attributes in these layers.